# How to use InterpolatingFunction generated by Mathematica 5.2 in version 8.0.1?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Let us interpolate the same data using *Mathematica* 5.2, 7.0.1 and 8.0.1:

```
Interpolation[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 0}}] // InputForm
```

The outputs are:

*Mathematica* 5.2:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 5}}, 
 {2, 0, True, False, {3}, {0}}, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, 
 {{0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {3}, {0}}, {Automatic}]
```

*Mathematica* 7.0.1:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 5}}, {3, 1, 0, {6}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {3}, {0}}, {Automatic}]
```

*Mathematica* 8.0.1:

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 5}}, {4, 3, 0, {6}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic}, 
 {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{0}, {1}, {3}, {4}, {3}, {0}}, {Automatic}]
```

The output of *Mathematica* 5.2 still works when used as input in version 7.0.1 but not in version 8.0.1. It seems that support of the old-style `InterpolatingFunction` was dropped in version 8. Is it possible to reuse `InterpolatingFunction` data generated by *Mathematica* 5.2 in version 8.0.1?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to extract the points from older version's `InterpolatingFunction` and then construct another `InterpolatingFunction` object in a newer version with those points?

Comment: @Leonid Not, this may be a solution. But I have no idea how to correctly extract the points from `InterpolatingFunction` in version 5.2 in a general way (the `InterpolatingFunction` may be returned by `NDSolve`).

Comment: @Alexey, look for the built-in package: "DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`", it contains functions that can extract range, data points, etc. from the InterpolatingFunction structure.

Comment: @István I am looking for version-independent solution. In this way I need to convert `InterpolatingFunction` into data set inside of version 5.2 because it is not guaranteed (and I have not checked whether it even works in v.8) that in newer versions of *Mathematica* ``DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` `` will support the old-style `InterpolatingFunction` from v.5.2.

Comment: @Alexey I don't remember exact details now and don't have version 5 currently installed, but I recall that this is a matter of extracting some `Part`(s) of `InterpolatingFunction` object. You can try some example to figure out which parts are responsible for the points.

Comment: I removed my posting after I realized (with Mr.Wizard's help) that I had misunderstood your question.

Comment: DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` should be version-independent, and is the best way to extract information from interpolating functions (since as you've noticed the InputForm representation is undocumented and subject to change.)

Comment: @István @Brett Thank you. I just realized that *Mathematica* 5.2 contains its own package ``DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`.``