# How to extract all the data from InterpolatingFunction for creating identical one?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In comments to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702766/how-to-use-interpolatingfunction-generated-by-mathematica-5-2-in-version-8-0-1) it was suggested to extract all the data from `InterpolatingFunction` generated by *Mathematica* 5.2 and then create another one in *Mathematica* 8. The suggested approach is to use functions defined in the `` DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` `` package for extraction of the data from the `InterpolatingFunction`. Trying it naively,

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]
ifun = First[
   x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == Exp[x[t]] - x[t], x[0] == 1}, 
     x, {t, 0, 10}]];
data = Transpose@{InterpolatingFunctionGrid[ifun], 
    InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[ifun]};
interpolationOrder = 
  Developer`FromPackedArray@
   InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[ifun];
ifun2 = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> interpolationOrder];
Table[ifun[x] - ifun2[x], {x, 0, 0.5160191740198963`, .1}]
```

I get significant difference between original function and reconstructed one:

```
{0., 2.13061*10^-7, 2.05087*10^-7, 2.46198*10^-7, 6.68937*10^-7, 
 1.5624*10^-7}
```

Looking at `InputForm` of these functions reveals that they are not identical. Is it possible to reconstruct the `InterpolatingFunction` through extraction of all the data from it and calling `Interpolation` on the extracted data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

Here is a general solution, in code:

```
Clear[reconstructInterpolatingFunction];
reconstructInterpolatingFunction[intf_InterpolatingFunction] :=
   With[{data = intf[[4, 3]], 
      step = Subtract @@ Reverse[ Take[intf[[4, 2]], 2]],
      order = 
          Developer`FromPackedArray@
              InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[intf],
      grid = InterpolatingFunctionGrid[intf]
      },
     Interpolation[
         MapThread[Prepend, {Partition[data, step], grid}], 
         InterpolationOrder -> order
     ]
   ];
```

Please see below for the explanation. Note however that the above code does rely on some details of the `InterpolatingFunction` object which may be version-specific, since apparently the API of `` DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` `` does not seem to allow to fully reconstruct the original object when values for function derivatives are important.

**End EDIT**

---

It appears that `NDSolve` includes the information on derivatives when constructing the `InterpolatingFunction`, which makes sense. In your case, that would include the first derivative, since your equation is first - order. But, this information is lost when we use the functions from the `` DifferentialEquations`
InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` `` package. The way to get it is to access the initial `InterpolatingFunction` object directly. Here is a simple example:

```
In[156]:= ifun=First[x/.NDSolve[{x'[t]==2x[t],x[0]==1},x,{t,0,0.1}]];

In[157]:= ifun[[4,3]]
Out[157]= {1.,2.,1.00002,2.00004,1.00004,2.00008,1.00457,2.00913,1.00911,2.01823,
1.01368,2.02736,1.02787,2.05573,1.04225,2.0845,1.05684,2.11368,1.07163,2.14326,
1.09328,2.18655,1.11536,2.23073,1.13789,2.27579,1.16088,2.32176,1.18433,2.36867,
1.20272,2.40545,1.2214,2.44281}
```

This suggests that each value is followed by the value of the  derivative, at this grid point.  Therefore, the way to construct a new object is something like this:

```
ifun5 = 
Interpolation[
   MapThread[Prepend, 
  {Partition[ifun[[4, 3]], 2], InterpolatingFunctionGrid[ifun]}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> (interpolationOrder)]
```

This uses the extended form of `Interpolation`, where one can also specify the values for derivatives. This passes our test:

```
In[161]:= Table[(1-ifun5[x]/ifun[x]),{x,0,0.1,.01}]
Out[161]= {0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.}
```

The way to determine, up to which derivative do we have the information in a given `InterpolatingFunction`, is to look at this part:

```
In[176]:= ifun[[4,2]]
Out[176]= {0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34}
```

In this case, the step is 2, so we have a value plus a first derivative. For, say, a second-order equation, the step will be 3, and you will need `Partition[...,3]`. So, you determine the order by getting the step in this part.

Now, the real thing:

```
In[162]:= 
ifun=First[x/.NDSolve[{x'[t]==Exp[x[t]]-x[t],x[0]==1},x,{t,0,10}]];
interpolationOrder=Developer`FromPackedArray@InterpolatingFunctionInterpolationOrder[ifun];
ifunnew = Interpolation[MapThread[Prepend,  
{Partition[ifun[[4,3]],2],InterpolatingFunctionGrid[ifun]}],
 InterpolationOrder->(interpolationOrder)];
Table[(1-ifunnew[x]/ifun[x]),{x,0,0.5,.1}]

During evaluation of In[162]:= NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.5160191740198969`, 
step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
Out[165]= {0.,0.,0.,1.11022*10^-16,0.,0.}
```